# Jenkins - Docker integration

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, docker

I'm looking for the best way to integrate Docker into Jenkins to execute build/test commands.
The best source I have found is this blog post: 
http://blog.howareyou.com/post/62157486858/continuous-delivery-with-docker-and-jenkins-part-i

It basically offers to wrap all execution commands with "docker run".

I would like to see better integrations with Jenkins plugin but I couldn't find anything in this area.
Could anyone suggest a good way to proceed? Is there any project on the way to address this?

Thanks

Comment: What is your actual question?

Answer (score 3):

[There's a second blog post](http://blog.howareyou.com/post/65048170054/continuous-delivery-with-docker-and-jenkins-part-ii) which goes into more detail about the setup. The missing piece was [dockerize](https://github.com/cambridge-healthcare/dockerize) which makes the Jenkins & Docker integration painless. If you look into the [Ruby app example](https://github.com/cambridge-healthcare/hi_sinatra-docker), there's a Vagrantfile which will set everything up for you, use that as the starting point for your own setup.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't you just create a shell script to setup the docker environment as you normally would (or better still push the docker container in to a private repo) and get Jenkins to pull it down and run the test suite inside docker using the daemonised mode?

Maybe you could use directory shares to drop the output of the test data so that Jenkins can read it and display?

Hopefully a point in the right direction...

Comment: Sorry I don't understand Monokrome, Isn't this what I suggested? push the slave image in to your Private docker repo and get the Jenkins instance to spark it up from a script as needed? while using the shares to drop the report files created by Jenkins to an accessible location - Recently completed a project similar to this that used python to orchestrate through AWS and ETCD to point the Jenkins box to a free instance to run the image on.

Comment: Hi @monokrome - Nothing was mentioned in the initial question regarding the Jenkins master/slave system thus nothing mentioned in my answer. Your comment is a moot point as the question was regarding the docker side of the infrastructure and in that respect has absolutely no difference to my answer! Without a view of the system you cannot comment on it! Furthermore, Jenkins Master/Slave topology is not ALWAYS the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

[This plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I think the plugin is doing something different - it talks about provisioning Jenkins slaves via docker i.e. additional build workers rather than allowing you to build / test applications that use docker?

Comment: Well, it should let you run builds inside Docker, which is how I interpreted the original question, but that question was pretty vague.